# Win11 - After upgrade SSD .. File Access Denied - You need to provide administrator permission... issue

Tags: ssd, permissions, windows-11

I've been having some problems after upgrading my SSD drive from 512 GB to 2 TB. I cloned the C drive, and since then I've been asked for permission to move, delete, write files, etc., actually the first time I edited a project with Premiere Pro when I tried to save it,  it tells me that I don't have permission, even though was the same I open to edit. I needed to save it with another name.

I used the Minitool Partition Wizard Free ver. 11.5 -> Option Migrate OS to SSD/HD Wizard. All the programs are running great: I fired it up and all went pretty smoothly. One thing I noticed, though, was when later I created a restore point, the old C: drive was there, even though it was not mounted, so it showed two C: Drives, the one after (actual) was off (I turn it on), and the old one, that was on, but offline.

The issue is that every time I need to do something with a file (not when I open it) it asks for permission, I have to click on continue. Looking for ways to fix it, I did the "net user xxx /active:yes" and also reduce the UAC to "Never" and still pops up the message.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

By the way, I created a new user just for testing purposes and it does not have that issue. I have Windows Pro 22H2, AMD Ryzen 9, 32 GB RAM.

Comment: Is this happening on the C: partition ?

Comment: What groups does the user belong to, and which groups have write access to the files?

Comment: @Albin: I Have only one user, the Administrator, Local, named Vic, and the later one, TestBox, and also Local and Adminstrator.

Comment: @harrymc: Yes, this is happening on the C: partition, I tried to leave it as it was before.

Comment: All I can suggest is that the clone didn't go well. Try perhaps to redo it, but using another product.

Comment: @LaPromesaVicToR it is not important how many other users you have. You need to look into the properties of the user, which groups does it belong to? Also you need to look into the properties of a file you can not access which users and usergroups have write access to the file. Please add the information to your question, e.g. as screenshots.

Comment: @LaPromesaVicToR also does this problem only with Premiere Pro? Also can you please post a screenshot of the permission messages?

Comment: @LaPromesaVicToR In addition to [harrymc's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1812877/win11-after-upgrade-ssd-file-access-denied-you-need-to-provide-administra#comment2848251_1812877), note that usually after cloning a drive, the new drive will have the disk signature of the old drive and so they cannot coexist in the same computer - Windows will complain about a disk signature collision. I suspect that your user account is in some way tied to the disk signature.